# Is there any way to "dual boot" xubuntu and lubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, lubuntu

I installed xubuntu on an old netbook and would like to try lubuntu in order to check where my performance constraints are.

Is there any way I can do that without having to install it again from the iso? I tried to `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`. It installed but I have not been able to switch XFCE to LXDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply install both environments on the same Ubuntu installation.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop xubuntu-desktop
```

Then at the login screen you should be able to choose which kind of session you want to launch each time you log in.  Here's what that looks like on lightdm (left) and gdm (right):

[image] [image]

Things to know:

- You'll only use one display manager, either lightdm or gdm, not both.  This will mainly affect just the login screen.  Once you install both the Lubuntu and Xubuntu desktop it may ask you which you prefer, and lightdm is probably preferable (though it's up to you).
- Different desktop environments tend to provide alternative software applications that do the same thing, and once you have multiple desktop environments installed you'll end up with software from each of them, so you'll have overlap.  See this as extra choice.

Comment: Well, thanks, I got both installed. (When I call it again it says they are already at the latest versions) But when I the computer boots it goes straight to the xubuntu login screen and I can find any options to call lubuntu. Am I missing something?

Comment: Found it, lost as a small icon top right of the login screen.

Comment: Good point, I've added an image to the answer for others' benefit.

Comment: Yea, in my case it was lost here: http://i.imgur.com/PHGaH04.jpg But hey, this sounds fun, I'll try them all. :B

Comment: Added that other image, hope you don't mind.